# Saving data from a text file into an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I got this text file of survey results:

[image: Survey_results]

I already managed to get Java to read it and display just fine using this code:

```
    import java.io.*;
    class Final {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception {
    File file = new File ("C:\\Users\\loren\\Desktop\\t\\respuestas.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String st; 
      while ((st=br.readLine()) !=null)
      System.out.println(st);
}
}
```

but I can't figure out how to save it on a 2D array, does anyone have any possible solutions?

Comment: Please see [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: Next to that, do you mind pasting the file in the post itself? That way we can copy/paste it, see what kind of white-space you are using etc.

Comment: (1-) `how to save it on a 2D array` - first of all I have no idea what that means. If you have a lines of data, why do you need a 2D array. 2) you don't know the size of the file and the size of an Array is hardcoded so don't use an array. Instead use an `ArrayList` which will grow as required.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to do this. In order to effectively place the file contents into a Two Dimensional (2D) Array you will need to know how large your array will need to be in order to properly fit everything into it so as not to run into the problem of generating an **ArrayOutOfBoundsException** when you fill that array. The size of the Array needs to be established before you can place elements into it. Things to consider are:

- Is it the right text file to begin with?
- How many valid data lines are there in the file?
- How many columns are there per line?
- Are there any unwanted lines within the file (like a header line
  or blank lines)?

This is why using a collection mechanism like ArrayList, Map, HashMap, etc is a good way to tackle this. You can always convert that collection into an Array when your done retrieving the data.

By looking at your example file (well...the image of it :/) it looks like there is a Header Line which briefly describes what each data column in each file line is for. You didn't specify whether or not you want this to be part of your 2D Array. You also didn't specify the data type for your 2D Array, will it be Object, String, or will it be Integer?

With the above in mind we have to assume that you don't want the header line to be placed into the Array and you simply want the raw integer data values contained within each row column. This then answers the Array Data Type question....Integer (int).

Here is one way to carry out the task:

```
public int[][] readDataFile(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException {
    ArrayList<int[]> list;
    // Try with resources...Auto closes scanner
    try (Scanner sRead = new Scanner(new File(filePath))) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        String line;
        int lineCounter = 0;
        while (sRead.hasNextLine()) {
            line = sRead.nextLine().trim();
            // Skip any blank lines
            if (line.equals("")) { continue; }
            lineCounter++;
            // Is it a valid data file?
            if (lineCounter == 1 && !line.startsWith("P1")) {
                // No it's not!
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Data File!",
                        "Invalid File!",
                        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                return null;
            }
            // Skip the Header Line
            else if (line.startsWith("P1")) { continue; }

            // Split the incomming line and convert the
            // string values to int's
            String[] strArray = line.split("\\s+");
            int[] intArray = new int[strArray.length];
            for(int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
                intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]);
            }
            // Add to ArrayList
            list.add(intArray);
        }
    }

    // Convert the ArrayList to a 2D int Array
    int[][] array = new int[list.size()][list.get(0).length];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.arraycopy(list.get(i), 0, array[i], 0, list.get(i).length);
    }
    return array;
}
```

And to use this method you might go with:

```
try {
    int[][] a = readDataFile("C:\\Users\\loren\\Desktop\\t\\respuestas.txt");
    for (int[] a1 : a) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a1));
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a list of String arrays and then convert this list into the 2D String array.
In this case, "result" will be your desired output.
Assumption: words in the input file are separated by tab

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
class Final {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File ("C:\\Users\\loren\\Desktop\\t\\respuestas.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String st;
        List<String[]> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        while ((st=br.readLine()) !=null) {
            resultList.add(st.split("\t"));
        }
        String[][] result = new String[resultList.size()][resultList.get(0).length];
        for(int i=0; i<resultList.size(); i++) {
            result[i] = resultList.get(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1-Read file data line by line with this class

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileReader {

    private String fileName, fileContent = null, line;

    public FileReader(String f) {
        fileName = f;
        reader();
    }

    private void reader() {
        try {
            fileContent = "";
            // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding
            Reader fileReader = new java.io.FileReader(fileName);

            // Wrapping FileReader in BufferedReader
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                fileContent += line;
                fileContent += '\n';
            }

            // Closing the file
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error reading file '" + fileName + "'");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get content of file
     * 
     * @return String
     */
    public String getFileContent() {
        return fileContent;
    }

}
```

2-Loop over lines and add them to specific index of array! You need a function which skip spaces in each line and extract just values.